# Magento Configurable Product Gallery Switch

Tags: image, magento, switch-statement, gallery, configurable

can somebody help me.
i have configurable products from simple and have 2 questions:

```
$galleryData = $_product->getData('media_gallery');
```

this way get all images from gallery for main product, how i can get all images for other options?

with this way i can get only image, small_image and thumbnail:

```
$mainprouct =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $_product->getSku())->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts();
```

how i can get all images for each option and reload media gallery on the fly?